# Selenium Webdriver (Java) - save classname value into the variable

Tags: java, selenium

I need store somehow a classname value - `class=\"system Win7\"` in to a variable.

```
  new WebDriverWait(Login.driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                    (By.xpath("//div[@class=\"system Win7\"]")))
```

I want use this variable after to choice a particular radio button with the same classname.

For example :

1) Save classname :

```
String v_test =  new WebDriverWait(Login.driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
                                (By.xpath("//div[@class=\"system Win7\"]"))).getSmth();
```

2) Then use v_test to find and click on the radio button

```
Login.driver.findElement
                (By.xpath("//div[@class="+v_test+"]")).click();
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAttribute()` will provide you the value of the attribute you use

```
String v_test = new WebDriverWait(Login.driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated (By.xpath("//div[@class=\"system Win7\"]"))).getAttribute("class")
```

Comment: Thanks Saifur, it is that what I looked for. Could you tell me please, how can I split the result from v_test variable? I mean, v_test contains "system Windows 64bit", is it possible to store in this variable only 64 bit?

Comment: Additional info: In case above, I don't now what result will be in the variable. So, I want get only 3rd word.

Comment: with the `Split` you can accomplish this. Use `string[] myVar = v_test.Split(' '); string targetVar = myVar.Last()` to split by the white space and grab targetVar which is the last element with index 2. Let me know if this is clear

Comment: Alternatively you also can do `string[] myVar = v_test.Split(' '); string targetVar = myVar[myVar.Count()-1])`

Comment: I just realized I was suggesting you C# code. Not sure if it worked for you. Let me know if you were able to convert

Comment: Thanks Saifur, no problem. I converted this to Java it's the same. So, I use : string[] myVar = v_test.Split(' '); string targetVar = myVar[2];